# Magento, Geb Based Test Suite

Tags: magento, regression, functional-testing, geb, test-suite

I know this is a long shot!

I am currently working on a Magento project that requires a functional test suite to test admin components as well as standard user journeys.

The project will involve editing some areas of core Magento and as such full coverage is required across the system.

My question is, is there by chance an existing Magento (Geb based) testing framework out there? I have started creating the suite myself but the sheer quantity of tests required combined with a rather tight deadline makes this option slightly unrealistic.

Any links or advice would be appreciated, if you're unaware of any Geb based testing frameworks, but have previously used another testing framework for Magento that worked well I'd love to hear about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Asking for external resources is off-topic. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?